# How to download Data URLs from command line?

Tags: linux, files, web

I only found JavaScript code for doing this through browser console.

For example if I copy image address from the first images from Google images search results grid I get a Data URL.

Commands that I tried and errors:

```
$ curl 'data:stuff' -o filename 
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

```
$ curl 'data:stuff' > filename
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

```
$ wget 'data:stuff' -O filename
Resolving data (data)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘data’
```

How can I download Data URL through command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data:` scheme is local in the context of a webpage while both `wget` and `curl` work with remote data. Perhaps what you're really looking for is `base64 -d` which allows to decode such data.

Lastly, the data URI scheme can be a lot longer/larger than your shell allows, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41755526 and I doubt you want to keep that much random data in your shell history.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a bit to the answer of Artem.

You can download xclip through your package manager and use a shell script (You should copy the Data URL):

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

data=$(xclip -out -selection clipboard)

ext=${data#*/}
ext=${ext%%;*}
ext=${ext/jpeg/jpg}

if [ $1 ]; then
        filename=$1
else
        filename=file
fi

echo "${data#*,}" | base64 -d > $filename.$ext
```

With no arguments filename is saved as file, otherwise it is your first argument.

Edit: Improved script -- thanks to Freddy's great comment.

Comment: There's no need for a temporary file: `echo "${data#*,}" | base64 -d > filename`.
You could also extract the image type and use it as suffix for the output filename, e.g. `ext=${data#*/}; ext=${ext%%;*}; ext=.${ext/jpeg/jpg}`.

Comment: If you’re on macOS, you can replace `xclip -out -selection clipboard` with `pbpaste` for the same results.